# XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col] when opening new stage (new window)

Tags: gradle, javafx, runtimeexception, unchecked-exception

I'm trying to switch from a window to another one.

This is my code:

```
public class SelectTypeController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button buttonVai;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> comboBox;
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane rootPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        ObservableList<String> observableListOfAccomodations = FXCollections.observableArrayList("1", "2", "3");
        comboBox.setItems(observableListOfAccomodations);
        buttonVai.setDisable(true);
    }

    @FXML
    public void comboChanged() {
        buttonVai.setDisable(false);
    }

    @FXML
    public void showCrudPage() {
        switch (comboBox.getValue()) {
            case "3":
                showCrudPageRestaurantScene();
                break;
        }
    }
    // this is giving problem
    public void showCrudPageRestaurantScene() {
        try {
            Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(SelectTypeController.class.getResource("/crud_restaurant.fxml"));
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

which manages the following fxml view
**select_type.fxml**

```
<AnchorPane
        fx:id="rootPane"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controllers.SelectTypeController" maxHeight="-Infinity"
        maxWidth="-Infinity"
        minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1280.0"
        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1">
    <ImageView fitHeight="800.0" fitWidth="1280.0" pickOnBounds="true">
        <Image url="images/3156482.jpg"/>
    </ImageView>
    <Pane layoutX="440.0" layoutY="307.0" opacity="0.8" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="400.0"
          style="-fx-background-color: #06BCAD; -fx-background-radius: 20;"/>
    <Pane layoutX="336.0" layoutY="206.0" prefHeight="336.0" prefWidth="608.0">
        <Label layoutX="200.0" layoutY="29.0" text="Seleziona una tipologia">
            <font>
                <Font size="20.0"/>
            </font>
        </Label>
        <Button fx:id="buttonVai" layoutX="260.0" layoutY="250.0" mnemonicParsing="false"
                onMouseClicked="#showCrudPage"
                style="-fx-background-color: #0078D7;" text="Vai" textFill="white"/>
    </Pane>
    <ComboBox fx:id="comboBox" layoutX="512.0" layoutY="371.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="292.0"
              promptText="Seleziona una tipologia"
              onAction="#comboChanged"/>

</AnchorPane>
```

I want that clicking on `Vai` button, I get redirected to:

```
public class CrudRestaurant {
    @FXML
    private Label labelDescription;
}
```

which manages

**crud_restaurant.fxml**

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="1080.0"
            fx:controller="controllers.CrudRestaurant"
            prefWidth="1920.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <Label layoutX="828.0" layoutY="415.0" text="Placeholder"/>
</AnchorPane>
```

Unfortunately I am getting an exception:

> javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,6]

and in particular:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/john/Desktop/myProject/build/resources/main/crud_restaurant.fxml

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2568)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at controllers.SelectTypeController.showCrudPageRestaurantScene(SelectTypeController.java:60)
    at controllers.SelectTypeController.showCrudPage(SelectTypeController.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1784)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3564)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8200(Scene.java:3492)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3860)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,6]
Message: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:652)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2538)
    ... 51 more
```

- How can I fix?javaf

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

I duplicated `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` in `crud_restaurant.fxml` file. My fault.

Just remove one redundant declaration.